# Запрос на youtrack с исключением

Tags: youtrack

Мне нужно создать запрос на youtrack с исключением, такого плана:
Исполнитель: я #Незавершенная **#Исключение Состояние: {На тестирование}**.
Как этот тег "исключение" использовать?
Т.е. мне нужно исключить задачи, которые на стадии тестирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запрос должен выглядеть так: #Незавершенная Состояние: -{На тестирование}
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/2017.2/Search-and-Command-Attributes.html#Operators